# mysql combine string + int value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE `numbering` (
    `numbering_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `document_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `current_no` int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `next_no` int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `pattern_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`numbering_id`)
);
```

I add in a record.

insert into numbering (document_type, current_no, next_no, pattern_name)
    values ('CUST_INV_NUM', 0, 1, 'INV');`

and i try to retrieve a value by doing:

```
select (pattern_name + '-' + next_no)
from numbering
where document_type = 'CUST_INV_NUM';`
```

I get value `1` returned. I am expecting  `INV-1`  how do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

i figured out the answer..

`select CONCAT(pattern_name, '-' , next_no) from numbering where document_type = 'CUST_INV_NUM';`

Answer (score 1):

Try using Concat (more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp))

```
select concat(pattern_name, '-', next_no)
from numbering
where document_type = 'CUST_INV_NUM';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below:

```
    select (pattern_name + '-' + str(next_no))
    from numbering
    where document_type = 'CUST_INV_NUM';
```

This query returns a string, with output as:'INV-1'